# Как установить Qt 4.8 на Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, qt, компиляция, установка, репозиторий

Как установить *Qt 4.8* на ноутбук с *Ubuntu Linux 14.04*?

Я установила *Qt Creator* и *Qt4 settings*, используя *Ubuntu Software Center* из меню на ноутбуке, но я вижу, что установился только *Qt5*.
У меня есть проекты, написанные под *Qt4*, мне нужно чтобы они собирались.

UPD: Я установила *libqt4-dev* с помощью *aptitude*. Что мне делать, чтобы *qmake* формировал *Makefile* с библиотеками *Qt4*, а не *Qt5*?

Comment: Версия ubuntu какая?

Comment: конечно, наилучший вариант ­— установить пакет(ы) из репозитория дистрибутива.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Понятие лучше очень субъективное. Поясните ваши критерии выбора.

Comment: libqt4-dev есть в репозитории

Answer (score 1):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/118878/how-to-install-qt-4-8-from-repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
```